# Jest obsolete snapshot warning causes test failure: ignore warnings when exiting Jest

Tags: jestjs, snapshot

I have a test suite/file that I have disabled. It has an associated snapshot file. For my particular situation I do not want to delete or update the snapshot file (long-story-short: it is used elsewhere).

So, Jest logs out just a warning, rather than a failure, for the obsolete snapshot. However Jest then exits with code 1 and my build fails. This happens despite no test actually failing.

Can I tweek the config to ignore obsolete snapshots? Or is there some other way to have Jest exit with code 0 after only a warning?

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to peep your package.json file?

Comment: Sorry @MarioPerez, I no longer have access to that repo.

Answer (score 1):

Add *--silent* to your test-ui script in the projects package.json

Comment: For others, the documentation says "Prevent tests from printing messages through the console." If this causes "Jest exit with code 0 after only a warning" then I'd be surprised.